# I get this error in windows CMD "stat: path too long for Windows" -- Azure cli

Tags: azure, cmd, path, azure-cli

I get this error in windows CMD `"stat: path too long for Windows"` whenever I execute this command below in my azure cli in windows CMD.

```
az group deployment create -g "testacsengine" --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Comment: Are there long directory paths in `azuredeploy.json` or `azuredeploy.parameters.json`? Has anything like this worked before?

Comment: @lit The json files are located in this path C:\devops\_output\demoacsengine. Its my first time to setup azure and k8s cluster.

Comment: I was suggesting to check for paths inside the .json files, not the path to the .json files.

Comment: @lit azuredeploy.json file contains paths in 1 line, like here in line 1956:

Comment: Try to use `--template-file "C:\devops_output\demoacsengineazuredeploy.json"`

Comment: @JoyWang Even if I’m inside that dir already whenever I execute that command?

Comment: @JoyWang still the same

Comment: @Ellie Just test the command `az group deployment create -g testgroup --template-file template.json` in Windows PowerShell ISE. It works well.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I got a different error now --> Azure Error: InvalidTemplateDeployment
Message: The template deployment 'azuredeploy' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '6
028b312-1c0d-48ee-8651-501eab8c2199'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage detai
ls.
Exception Details:
        Error Code: QuotaExceeded
        Message: Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 0, Additional
requested: 14.

Comment: @Ellie Do you mind providing your template?

Comment: @Ellie If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, if you already install the Azure CLI model, you can execute the CLI command in CMD or Windows PowerShell ISE.

For the deployment of Azure template, you can just use the command `az group deployment create -g "charlesTest" --template-file template.json` in the directory of your template.

Or use the absolute path like this `az group deployment create -g "charlesTest" --template-file D:\template.json`. Of curse, you need to get authentication with the command `az login` first.

If you still get the error when you do this, the error must be inside your template. You should check your template correctly.

For more details about template deployment, see [`az group deployment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-create).